# How to get items with superior and inferior relationship from a flat array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
[
    [
        'id'=>1,
        'parent'=>0
    ],
    [
        'id'=>2,
        'parent'=>1
    ],
    [
        'id'=>3,
        'parent'=>0
    ],
    [
        'id'=>4,
        'parent'=>2
    ],
    [
        'id'=>5,
        'parent'=>0
    ],
    [
        'id'=>6,
        'parent'=>0
    ]
]
```

For example my function is like this:

```
public static function getAllChildren($categories, $parent_id)
```

I want data like this,Get data by an id:

```
[
    [
        'id'=>1,
        'parent'=>0
    ],
    [
        'id'=>2,
        'parent'=>1
    ],
    [
        'id'=>4,
        'parent'=>2
    ]
]
```

I've tried static method recursion and static variables, but, when calling this method from multiple places, the data stacks up（google translate）

Comment: How are you deciding which items to select from the list?

Comment: Do you want data grouped by their parent id ?

Comment: I want to extract all subordinates by parent id, I have revised the problem, just didn't describe it clearly

Comment: I was stupid and suddenly found a low-level error. The recursive method written before is actually effective, but I did not assign the result of array_merge, resulting in the data not being merged after recursion.（google translate）

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
$temp = array_unique(array_column($arr, 'parent'));
$unique_arr = array_intersect_key($arr, $temp);
```

Comment: I found that the data I want is wrong, I have revised the question, the data I want has a relationship between the upper and lower levels, it may be multi-layer（google translate）

Answer (score 0):

Try this. However I am sure there is a way to solve this problem more efficiently and reduce time complexity.

```
<?php

function getAllChildren($categories, $parent_id, $arr = []) {
    for ($i=0; $i < count($categories); $i++) {
        if($categories[$i]['parent'] == $parent_id) {
            array_push($arr, $categories[$i]);
            return getAllChildren($categories, $categories[$i]['id'], $arr);
        }
    }
    
    return $arr;
};

$data = [
    [
        'id'=>1,
        'parent'=>0
    ],
    [
        'id'=>2,
        'parent'=>1
    ],
    [
        'id'=>3,
        'parent'=>0
    ],
    [
        'id'=>4,
        'parent'=>2
    ],
    [
        'id'=>5,
        'parent'=>0
    ],
    [
        'id'=>6,
        'parent'=>0
    ]
];

$result = getAllChildren($data, 0);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I can't find it when there are multiple children, but I learned the trick of treating the result as a parameter, thanks.